# What's wrong with this sed ? (trying to delete a line)

Tags: bash, sed

I'm new in bash, and I'm trying to delete a line in a file I'm creating.

So without further ado :

```
if [[ $(ls -1 | grep 'fichiers.toCheck' | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]; then
touch fichiers.toCheck
fi

find . -name '*.mp4' > fichiers.toCheck

while read p; do
  echo $p
  sed -i "$p/d" ./fichiers.toCheck
done <fichiers.toCheck
```

Console is giving me this:

```
sed: 1: "./fichiers.toCheck": invalid command code .
```

I'm suspecting sed interprets the "/" in the line as an argument (the line is something like "./nosound.mp4".

What's your guess?

edit 2 = the correct syntax was with -i.bak

```
sed -i.bak "s@$p@@" fichiers.toCheck
```

edit = so here's my experiments :

1

```
while read p; do
  echo $p
  sed -i "/$p/d" fichiers.toCheck
done <fichiers.toCheck
```

And I get :

```
sed: 1: "fichiers.toCheck": invalid command code f
```

2

```
sed -i "@$p@d" fichiers.toCheck
```

and same error :

```
sed: 1: "fichiers.toCheck": invalid command code f
```

Comment: The syntax is n`d`, for example `15d`, or `/`regexp`/d`, for example `/Blondie/d`.

Comment: I've edit my post to answer you!

Comment: By the way , you can check if a file exist with just `if [[ ! -e file ]];then touch file;fi` or in one line `[[ ! -e file ]] && touch file`

Comment: I have to say, I am not following your logic at all :(  You touch a file if it doesn't exist, but the overwrite it any way with your find command (so too bad if it did already exist).  Then you want to loop over all values in the file and actively delete the values at the same time from the same file.  Even if it did work, you would end up with an empty file.  Maybe you need to explain what you are actually doing as the code makes little sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sed` syntax is wrong, to delete a line containing a pattern from a `bash` variable. Also being using `FreeBSD` native `sed` in `OS X` use the `-i.bak` for in-place edits.

```
sed -i.bak "/$p/d" fichiers.toCheck
```

If you suspect your variable contains `/` change the `sed` separator to `@` and use the traditional pattern `s/<pattern>/<replacement>/` style with the replacement part set to empty, i.e.

```
sed -i.bak "s@$p@@" fichiers.toCheck
```

Comment: @Kenneth: it was a wrong syntax, try `sed -i.bak "s@$p@@" fichiers.toCheck
`

Comment: Mmm still got the invalid command code f :/ BTW I'm on macOS, dunno if that changes something but...